# <marquee> tag, show text immediately

Tags: html

The text now with `<marquee>` tahg appears on one side only when the other disappear completely.
You need to wait until all the text disappears and only then he come from other side.
How to make text disappear soon appear on the other side?

I hope you understand my problems.

Comment: You shouldn't use `<marquee>` since it's not even part of HTML4, let alone HTML5. Build your own with Javascript.

Comment: @DanMan - Marquee is coming back with CSS3 the last time I saw. The jQuery plugin's I have used in the past haven't been much good (Although it is fairly straight forward to build your own as mentioned).

Comment: @Mig That would make it a CSS attribute, rather than a HTML tag, which is correct since 'scroll this text left to right' is presentational rather than describing the type of content it contains. At the moment, it has an experimental implementation (-webkit-marquee) in Safari/Chrome but no other browser. It _still_ won't do what the OP is requesting. (I'm sure you know this but since many HTML novices may stumble upon this question searching for help with the marquee tag, I'm writing this comment for posterity).

Comment: Just voting up the question to raise awareness to others that this tag is no longer part of HTML and really never was, as it was a Microsoft pet tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow the `<marquee>` tag - not seen that for a while. It has all sorts of cross-browser problems - it doesn't work at all in Firefox. It's not actually in the HTML standard, it was a custom tag introduced by Microsoft.

The problem you describe is the way that it works, and there's no way of customising it. The only thing you *could* do (and I can't stress how strongly I would recommend **not** doing this) would be to duplicate the text a few times and put lots of spaces between it. That would simulate the effect you're trying to achieve using only the marquee tag.

However, that should be an absolute last resort. You are almost certainly better off using JavaScript to do this. It's easier to customise, and will work in all browsers.

Here's some customisable JavaScript: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm or you can use a jQuery plugin like http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html.

Comment: [It works in Firefox 4](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html), at least.

Comment: I am guilty of using marquee on a couple of sites in the past, but only because of client requests that I didn't want to spend the 3 minutes implementing a javascript version on. Never had a problem with it working though, actually older jquery plugins used to render worse than normal marquee. I'm actually using one of the ones you posted now.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think I'd checked it in Firefox since v1.5. It's not working on Firefox 4 on the Mac.

Comment: It's one of those things that's not supposed to work but just does. On a related note, `<blink>` [does work with HTML5](http://isblink.partofhtml5.com/) and is working for me on FF4 as well.

Comment: @Wesley I've used it myself, where the client had seen something in a marquee tag and wanted it to look exactly the same. But the moment they want to customise the behaviour, I would switch to JavaScript.