# HTML marquee not working in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, uiwebview

Please see below function.

```
-(void)loadHTMLinWebView
{   
    objWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    objWebView.opaque = NO;
    objWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    objWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NSString *strTemp = @"<html><body style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; text-align:center"><marquee behavior="alternate" style="font-family:Marker Felt;font-size:20px; color:#A52A2A;">Test</marquee></font></body></html>";
    [objWebView loadHTMLString:strTemp baseURL:nil];
    [self addSubview:objWebView];
}
```

Above is the code that I had written for loading HTML in UIWebView.

But when I am running this code in `iOS 4.0` device, It is working well and I saw marquee effect in Webview but running this code in `iOS 5.1` device, It is not showing the marquee effect, It is just showing the text.

Don't know what is happening there.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your code I found that `behavior="alternate"` is causing problem to stop scrolling. If you put `behavior="scroll"` than it will scroll but not as per your requirement.

If you look for alternates than there is other answer which may be helpful to you.

Here are few links to discussion which discuss this problem and recommends not to use marquee.

[link1](http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=14527) 
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842185/marquee-tag-show-text-immediately) 
[link3](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/Cggw0G83IhQ)

**Update**

Wowo ! This is something interesting. I checked again and found that it does work but not for small strings. It works for somewhat large strings. Still no clue about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

AS alternative you can create same thing with UIView and Timer. Please refer below URL

https://github.com/jeffhodnett/JHTickerView

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKTickerViewDemo

https://github.com/caydenliew/CLTickerView

Comment: +1. Its good to provide alternates for the problem. But initially we must help to resolve the problem if possible.