# Marquee and static UILabel text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

In my application i have two options to display text in UILabel .First is to use marquee like effect , so that long text can scroll along its width. I am using size of 350 for marquee. Other option is called static. In this however long is the text it should not marquee and show whole text in UILabel. UIlabel should adjust its font and size so as to fit in the frame of uiview i.e width = 480 and height  = 320 in landscape mode. I have completed with the marquee animation but i am not able to figure out how to display static tex in uilabel so that it will changes its size and font according to the length of text.

Comment: According to my opinion create UIView custom class and add UIWebview in it and load html string using marquee tag in webview.. as It worked for me..

Comment: I have used animations for marquee and it is working completely fine. I want to fit the text in multiple line of UIlabel. And also should change its font size accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS alternative you can create same thing with UIView and Timer. Please refer below URL

https://github.com/jeffhodnett/JHTickerView

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKTickerViewDemo

https://github.com/caydenliew/CLTickerView

[HTML marquee not working in iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459861/html-marquee-not-working-in-ios-5-1/10459957#10459957)